# Trying to uncenter a column on large size

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I have a row with 4 columns in it. On the medium size the first 3 columns as set to a medium size of 4, the last column is set to a size of 4, but it also centered.

```
<div class="row text-center">
<div class="columns small-12 medium-4 large-3">
<div class="columns small-12 medium-4 large-3">
<div class="columns small-12 medium-4 large-3">
<div class="columns small-12 medium-4 medium-centered large-3 large-uncentered">
```

Here is an image to show what is happening.
[image]

Comment: Can you share your CSS?

Comment: There is no custom CSS, just foundation css that is included in the framework. That's why I'm confused as to why its not working, I'm just using these stuff right out of the box so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `box-sizing`

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

It makes elements have padding and border included in the elements width and height.